# wrap post in div, and the comment in same div. reproduce reddit nested comment css

Tags: php, mysql, css

I have been trying to mimick the nested comment system that reddit use. Now i have a app that does in a way look like what it was intended to look. But, if you have a look at the reddit style:

[image]

I haven't been able to reproduce the lines that attach the previous answer.

My thought is that is nested divs somehow.

currenlty I'm outputting the db data lik this:

```
<?php if(!empty(getMessage())): ?>
  <div class="container">
      <h1>The nested comment exampel!</h1>
  <?php    foreach (getMessage() as $value){ ?>
      <div class="level_<?= $value->level; ?> comment" id="<?= $value->id; ?>">
          <?php if($value->visible == 0) : ?>
          <?= $value->date ?><br>
          Deleted
          <?php elseif($value->visible == 1): ?>
          <?= $value->date ?> <a href="index.php?delete=<?= $value->id ?>">X</a> <?= 'id: '. $value->id . ', sort order: ' .$value->sort_order . ', level: '.$value->level ;?><br>
          <?= $value->comment_text ?>

          <form action="index.php" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $value->id ?>" />
          <input type="hidden" name="parent" value="<?= $value->reply_to ?>" />
          Add comment: <input type="text" name="svar">
          <input type="submit">
          </form>

          <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
<?php } endif; ?>
      </div>
```

And i have solved the left margin with a simpel (not so clean) solution with

```
<style>
    div.level_ {
    margin-left: 00px;
}
div.level_1 {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
    div.level_2 {
    margin-left: 40px;
}
    div.level_3 {
    margin-left: 60px;
}
        div.level_4 {
    margin-left: 80px;
}
        div.level_5 {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
    div.level_6 {
    margin-left: 120px;
}
    div.level_7 {
    margin-left: 140px;
}
    div.level_8 {
    margin-left: 160px;
}
        div.level_9 {
    margin-left: 180px;
}
        div.level_10 {
    margin-left: 200px;
}
</style>
```

I have these columns in the database
`id`,`comment_text`, `reply_to`, `sort_order`, `level`, `date`, `ip`, `visible`

And my "clone" or what you can call it simply reads the parent id (reply to) and updates all rows if a comment is addad before. if a comment is addad to the first comment/post, the sort_order is simply +1.

- But, how can i output a "comment" inside the post. and a answer
  comment inside its parent comment.

Currently it looks like this

[image]

**EDIT**

To make it clear i have prepared some mock up data.

Here is the result I'm looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/wv9j9ueo/
With dis data http://pastie.org/10400764 notice the `level` column. Shouldn't it be possible to foreach the column `level`from 0 and then keep going until there is nothing left (notice that the can be two or more of the same value).

Answer (score 1):

If you put divs into  the parents your code looks prettiest:

```
<div class="comment">
    <p>The comment</p>
    <div class="comment">
         <p>The comment</p>
         <div class="comment"> <p>The comment</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Css

```
  .comment {
       margin-left: 15px;
       border-left : 2px dotted blue;
       padding : 0 10px;
 }
```

### PHP

```
<?php if(!empty(getMessage())): ?>
  <div class="container">
      <h1>The nested comment exampel!</h1>
  <?php   
      $i=0; //initialize flag
      foreach (getMessage() as $value){ ?>
      <div class="comment" id="<?= $value->id; ?>">
       //you don't need level class
          <?php if($value->visible == 0) : ?>
          <?= $value->date ?><br>
          Deleted
          <?php elseif($value->visible == 1): ?>
          <?= $value->date ?> <a href="index.php?delete=<?= $value->id ?>">X</a> <?= 'id: '. $value->id . ', sort order: ' .$value->sort_order . ', level: '.$value->level ;?><br>
          <?= $value->comment_text ?>

          <form action="index.php" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $value->id ?>" />
          <input type="hidden" name="parent" value="<?= $value->reply_to ?>" />
          Add comment: <input type="text" name="svar">
          <input type="submit">
          </form>

          <?php endif; ?>

<?php 
        $i++; //sum flag

    }
    for($x=0; $x<=$i; $x++) { //paint div closers
           echo '</div>' ;
   }  
 ?>
<? endif; ?>
      </div>
```

See it working

http://jsfiddle.net/jc5104st/1/

Comment: Yes thats the way i want it! But it seems to be the foreach that i can't really figure out.

Comment: If you use PHP to retrieve data from DB, and javascript to append the elements, it's really easy. If not, in the foreach you can remove `</div>` in the end of the loop, count how many iterations was passed and then, when foreach finish, paint all `</div>` depending on the number of iterations

Comment: Sounds like a good idea! But unfortunately i don't know how to do that in javascript.

Comment: In javascript, the best and cleanest solution is to paint a json with php that contains all data of the elements. Then with javascript, you read and iterate json data and append each element to the last handled element. It's all, but you need to know some javascript. Jquery makes this task even easier

Comment: The problem is that i don't know javascript, nor jQuery :/

Comment: I So try the php solution. Remove `</div>` in the end of foreach to allow the comment don't close. Add an `i=0` flag and make `i++` each iteration. Then when foreach is finished, make a `for(x=0; x <= i; x++) { echo '</div>' ;}` and that's all

Comment: Could you please update your first answer with your php solution and with a code snipp/fiddler. Im having a hard time with this foreach. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It was edited. I don't test it, I am in mobile. So don't copy and paste and critic if don't work, understand the code and try make it run

Comment: Thank you! The code is working as your fiddle! But is it not working as i want it to work. Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wv9j9ueo/ you will notice that their is "sub" comments. A comment can be commented, thats way (i think) the level column has do be their.

Comment: I don't understand, what's your problem? It's working fine

Comment: Yes in a way its woking. This is how it looks like: http://imgur.com/GooNHN7 but it should look like this http://imgur.com/lSiaHRD The first example is from your code snipp. The second (how i should look like) is a mockup.

Comment: In this case open a new question and don't modify the problem in this. I answer to your question (first time you're asked). Please accept this and open a new question. I'm glad to help you again